# Weird behavior with Laravel Slack Notifications

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, webhooks, slack-api

So I am setting up a exception handler that send a Slack notification every time an exception happens in the application, I have also setup this when a Complaint(Model) is created and that work fine. But in my Exception/Handle.php I have this setup.

```
Notification::route('slack', env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'))->notify(new ExceptionCreated($exception));
```

The webhook does exist and it does work. And while dd() every possible step I know that it hits the ExceptionCreated in Notifications. So there I have this code.

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\SlackMessage;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Throwable;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class ExceptionCreated extends Notification 
{
    use Queueable;

/**
     * @var Throwable
     */
public $exception;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @param \Throwable $exception
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Throwable $exception)
{
    $this->exception = $exception;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['slack'];
}

/**
 * Get the slack representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param mixed $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\SlackMessage
 */
public function toSlack($notifiable)
{   
    dd($this->exception);
    //and a lot of code here but that doesn't matter
}
```

Now when I dump inside the constructor I can see the exception is being passed correctly, but it never fires the toSlack function and I have no idea why, I have cleared cache, dump autoload and nothing seems to be working, as I said I have this exact code for my Complaints and that works fine. So any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Are you running your queue worker? Given this is queueable?

Comment: Yes, as I said i have it setup identically for another model and it works fine there, also i have run php artisan queue:restart , and that didnt fix anything